# Checking if RoomDatabase is empty while using LiveData

Tags: android, dao, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to use `RoomDatabase` in my Android App. And I am using `LiveData` to be able to refresh my changes automatically inside my fragment.

The first time I am running my app I am getting the data from the API, creating my `RoomDatabase` and storing my data.

The second time I run my app I want to check if my DataBase is not empty. But while using `LiveData`: the following code is returning null.

```
AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).getRecipeDao().getAllRecipes().getValue();
```

I have read that "if the response is an observable data type, such as Flowable or LiveData, Room watches all tables referenced in the query for invalidation".

How to check if my RoomDatabase has data or is empty?

Comment: the getValue() call returns null?

Comment: yes.. even when I have filled my database.

Comment: Okay did you read through the explanation below. I tried implementing without adding an observer and my getValue() was also returning null. Once i added the observer i was then able to get the values from the database correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after implementing myself I found that you need to do a few things:

1. Make sure you have an `Observer` for changes to the `LiveData`
2. You need to call `observeForever(Observer<T> observer)` unless you are using a `LiveCyclerOwner` then use that instead with: `observe (LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)`
3. Finally, there is an interesting note on `getValue()`:

> Returns the current value. Note that calling this method on a
>   background thread does not guarantee that the latest value set will be
>   received

So to reiterate, I think your approach does not work.

You will need to create some type of separate check rather than use a method that returns a `LiveData` class as noted since it does not guarantee the latest value set is received by calling `getValue()`.

I would recommend something super simple in the end such as adding a new method to your `Dao`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM recipes LIMIT 1")
Recipe getAnyRecipe();
```

and do this check looking for `null` to see if anything exists in the recipes table.

Comment: As per the Observer, I have used MediatorLiveData to observe LiveData. 
getAnyRecipe() helped me fix my problem. Thank you!